# BIOS issues since 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, asus, bios

Ever since I upgraded to 11.04 I have the following issues on my dual boot (Windows 7) system:
- When I reboot from Ubuntu, I will hear the BIOS beep twice and the BIOS will show a message that it couldn't boot the first time (hence the second beep),
- When I shut down from Ubuntu and cold boot my pc in Windows the pc will suddenly reboot after login. The reboot is not caused by a BSOD.

My motherboard is an Asus Striker Extreme.

Did anyone else have this weird issue?

Comment: @bswarm The 2nd beep is clearly from a restart because the screen goes blank and the memory tested ok.

Comment: My advice is to determine the make of BIOS and check out the meaning of the beep codes. Do not assume an OS is causing the problem. It might be advance warning of a failure of hardware.

Comment: Maybe there is a BIOS update? http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/Striker_Extreme/#download

Answer (score 2):

No.

However Matthew Garrett [recently wrote about problems getting some machines to reboot cleanly](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/3561.html).  It's possible that your machine might be one of them, and that a newer kernel might fix the problem.  I don't know how likely that is, and even if it is, I don't know if you can expect a backport of the fix in Natty, or if you'll have to wait until 11.10 is released.

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find an update for the BIOS. If that fails than I'll create a bugreport on Launchpad.